# Python: function which finds a prime, but also determines if the parameters entered is the sum of 2 primes

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

Would appreciate some feedback on a challenge I was recently given.  In an interview the challenge was to write a function which takes only one number f(n) and returns a True if the number entered meets these conditions:

1. A prime number (which is easy enough to check)
2. the sum of 2 prime numbers

Without being able to enter a second number, there'd be a lot of recursions in the algorithm. Any pointers?

An example of a True would be f(5) where 5 is a prime number and the sum of 2 and 3 (which are also prime).  But 1 + 4 is also 5, which is false.

Comment: While this does look like a bit of an interesting problem, this question will likely be closed. I recommend adding the code that you've tried so far and stating exactly where you're stuck. Otherwise, this will look like a classic "gemme teh codez" request.

Comment: find all the prime numbers between your given number and see if there's a sum that makes up your number

Comment: condition is `or` or `and` ?

Comment: What Christian said – it's a fun problem but a "bad" question because you haven't shown any work yet

Comment: Why would 1+4 matter?  Neither of those is prime.  Also, note that the only way a prime can be the sum of 2 primes is if it's the larger of twin primes (another prime + 2).  [Where are you stuck](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) on the algorithm?

Comment: Thanks.  Just to be clear, I was not looking for a give-me-the-code to, but more of a direction.  Here's what I have, which is only to check the prime number.  I'm spinning on the second condition of finding a sum.                      import math

def check_prime(n):

    if n <= 1:
        return False

    if n % 2 == 0 and n > 2:
        return False
    for i in range(3, int(math.sqrt(n)) + 1, 2):
        if n % i == 0:
            return False
    return True

print (check_prime(10))

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the number is prime (which you claim is easy enough), then check to see if two less than that number is prime.

There is only one even prime number (2). Since the the sum of two odd numbers is always even, the sum of any other two prime numbers (other than 2) will always be even, and therefore not prime.  This means if a number, n, is prime, and is also the sum of two primes, then n-2 must be prime.

Comment: j15, thanks for the direction.  I missed the mark when given the problem in a coderpad session.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the hint and help from this code which is using itertool approach :

```
import itertools


user_input=int(input())

def primecheck(int_1):   #prime no check function
    check_list = []

    for item in range(1,int_1):
        if int_1%item==0:
            check_list.append(item)
    if len(check_list)==1:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1


if primecheck(user_input)==0:  #if prime no is sum of two other prime no check function
    def checker(int_2):
        all = []               
        for item in range(2, user_input):
            all.append(item)

        only_prime = []
        for item_1 in all:
            if primecheck(item_1) == 0:
                only_prime.append(item_1)

        for check in itertools.product(only_prime, repeat=2):
            sum_of_two_prime = check[0] + check[1]

            if sum_of_two_prime == user_input:

                return "{} is prime number and it is sum of {} and {}".format(user_input,check[0],check[1])
        return "it is prime but not sum of any two other prime numbers"



    print(checker(user_input))

else:
    print("Its not prime , Please Enter a prime number")
```

Test_case1:

```
    17
    it is prime but not sum of any two other prime numbers

    5
    5 is prime number and it is sum of 2 and 3

    13
    13 is prime number and it is sum of 2 and 11
```